# FROM_UNIXTIME() not working mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table alert_log has column name date_dt (type varchar 50) which stores unix timestamp data 
example data : 1518783503000

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(date_dt) AS 'date_formatted' from alert_log
```

it always returns null.please help i would like to convert the example unix data as Fri Feb 16 2018

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is because `1518783503000` is not a valid MySQL unix time.

Divide by 1000 to get it right because unix time is in seconds and you stored it in milliseconds.

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(date_dt / 1000) AS 'date_formatted' 
from alert_log
```

Comment: its a valid timestamp value. I try to convert using javascript it works perfect. but i want to know how to convert in mysql query .you can refer https://jsfiddle.net/n60qgxa5/1/

Comment: In MySQL UNIXTIME is: *seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC*

Comment: @NandhiniPriya Use a site [like this one](https://www.epochconverter.com), which would have detected that you are using milliseconds.